# Incorrect PHP sizeof or count

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

The following is a print_r of an array converted from an XML document:

```
Array
    (
        [layer1] => Array
            (
                [item] => Array
                    (
                        [item-id] => 1886731
                        [item-name] => Bad Dog
                        [category] => pets
                        [link] = http://www.baddog.com/
                    )
            [total-matched] => 1
        )
    )
```

For the above array,  sizeof($myarray[layer1][item]) should return 1, but it returns 4. I get the correct number of "item" items if there are more than one of them. The same error happens regardless of whether I use "sizeof" or "count". How do I get PHP to return "1" when there is only one item?

Consequently, if there is one item, I can't access item-name using array[layer1][item][0][item-name], I have to use array[layer1][item][item-name].

Comment: What are you using to construct your array structure?, this is what is causing your problem. Not `sizeof` or `count`.

Comment: If you're really using bare strings (ie, `$array[layer1]` and not `$array['layer1']` you should first of all change that, see [the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), search for "Why is $foo[bar] wrong?".

Comment: `sizeof` tells you how many elements are in an array. I'm pretty sure this very simple and basic functionality is working perfectly fine. You are simply applying it wrong. To help you with that, we'd need yo see your code though.

Comment: Use `count` function ans set the second parameter to `COUNT_RECURSIVE`

Comment: Use [SimpleXML](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). There is no good reason to convert an XML document to an array to read it.

Comment: Well there is, array are easier to code against and using the function that I use I can get attributes as well. Here is the function I use: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php#105697

Comment: use `var_dump` instead of `print_r`, it's got a bit more detail

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a world of difference between:

```
$array1 = array(
  'layer1' => array(
    'item' => array(
      '0' => array(
        'item-id' => 123123,
        'item-name' => 'Bad Dog',
        'category' => 'pets',
        'link' => 'http://www.baddog.com/',
      ),
    )
  )
);
```

and:

```
$array2 = array(
  'layer1' => array(
    'item' => array(
       'item-id' => 123123,
       'item-name' => 'Bad Dog',
       'category' => 'pets',
       'link' => 'http://www.baddog.com/',
    )
  )
);
```

Basically they are different structures, and PHP is correct to return the following:

```
count($array1['layer1']['item']);
/// = 1 (count of items in the array at that point)

count($array2['layer1']['item']);
/// = 4 (count of items in the array at that point)
```

If you wish to get a count for `['layer1']['item']` that makes sense to your app, you will always need `['layer1']['item']` to be an array containing multiple array structures... i.e. like `$array1` above. This is the reason why I ask what is generating your array structure because - whatever it is - it is basically intelligently stacking your array data depending on the number of items, which is something you don't want.

Code that can cause an array to stack in this manner normally looks similar to the following:

```
/// $array = array(); /// this is implied (should be set elsewhere)

$key = 'test';
$newval = 'value';

/// if we are an array, add a new item to the array
if ( is_array($array[$key]) ) {
  $array[$key][] = $newval;
}
/// if we have a previous non-array value, convert to an array
/// containing the previous and new value
else if ( isset($array[$key]) ) {
  $array[$key] = array($array[$key],$newval);
}
/// if nothing is set, set the $newval
else {
  $array[$key] = $newval;
}
```

Basically if you keep calling the above code, and tracing after each run, you will see the following structure build up:

```
$array == 'value';
```

then

```
$array == array(0 => 'value', 1 => 'value');
```

then

```
$array == array(0 => 'value', 1 => 'value', 2 => 'value');
```

It's the first step in this process that is causing the problem, the `$array = 'value';` bit. If you modify the code slightly you can get rid of this:

```
/// $array = array(); /// this is implied (should be set elsewhere)
$key = 'test';
$newval = 'value';

/// if we are an array, add a new item to the array
if ( is_array($array[$key]) ) {
  $array[$key][] = $newval;
}
/// if nothing is set, set the $newval as part of an subarray
else {
  $array[$key] = array($newval);
}
```

As you can see all I've done is delete the itermediate `if statement`, and made sure when we discover no initial value is set, that we always create an array. The above will create a structure you can always count and know the number of items you pushed on to the array.

```
$array == array(0 => 'value');
```

then

```
$array == array(0 => 'value', 1 => 'value');
```

then

```
$array == array(0 => 'value', 1 => 'value', 2 => 'value');
```

**update**

Ah, I thought so. So the array is generated from XML. In this case I gather you are using a predefined library to do this so modifying the code is out of the question. So as others have already stated, your best bet is to use one of the many XML parsing libraries available to PHP:

http://www.uk.php.net/simplexml

http://www.uk.php.net/dom

When using these systems you retain more of an object structure which should be easier to count. Both the above also support xpath notation which can allow you to count items without even having to grab hold of any of the data.

**update 2**

Out of the function you've given, this is the part that is causing your arrays to stack in the manner that is causing the problem:

```
$children = array();
$first = true;
foreach($xml->children() as $elementName => $child){
    $value = simpleXMLToArray($child,$attributesKey, $childrenKey,$valueKey);
    if(isset($children[$elementName])){
        if(is_array($children[$elementName])){
            if($first){
                $temp = $children[$elementName];
                unset($children[$elementName]);
                $children[$elementName][] = $temp;
                $first=false;
            }
            $children[$elementName][] = $value;
        }else{
            $children[$elementName] = array($children[$elementName],$value);
        }
    }
    else{
        $children[$elementName] = $value;
    }
}
```

The modification would be:

```
$children = array();
foreach($xml->children() as $elementName => $child){
    $value = simpleXMLToArray($child,$attributesKey, $childrenKey,$valueKey);
    if(isset($children[$elementName])){
        if(is_array($children[$elementName])){
            $children[$elementName][] = $value;
        }
    }
    else{
        $children[$elementName] = array($value);
    }
}
```

That should stop your arrays from stacking... however if you have any other part of your code that was relying on the previous structure, this change may break that code.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I got the issue as soon as you put those examples! :)

I am using this function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php#105697

Comment: no problem, it's always best to go through interations one step at a time :) hopefully the modified code I've just added should sort your problem out...?

Comment: Unfortunately, stacking all child array would require too much code change. Is there a way just the array[layer1][item] is the level that is always stacked? So instead of [layer1][item] I always have [layer1][item][0]. That would require the least amount of code change elsewhere...